# XmlSerialization not working in .NET Core 2

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, xmlserializer, coreclr

I have .NET Core 2.0 application. The Code below serializes the object using XmlSerializer and POST the content to api. (default is DataContractSerializer so i am explicitly passing XmlSerializer)

```
   // use XmlSerializer
   var formatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter();
   formatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;

   // Post as Xml
   var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync<TSource>(url, source, formatter).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here the request object

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Request", Namespace = "")]
public class RequestDTO
{
    [XmlArray("Invoices")]
    [XmlArrayItem("InvoiceId")]
    public string[] Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

However POST fails with HTTP 400 error. When i check the request in fiddler i noticed the following

[image]

so serialization wrapping the actual request around `bd` and `o`. 
Not sure why?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: whats wrong with the post?

Comment: Well, assuming there is no general bug putting random characters in your body, it's something you do. And we don't know what you do. So it's hard to help without a [mcve].

Comment: `bd` and `0` are the length encodings of the `chunked` transfer encoding